# Typescript mapped type with filtered keys

Tags: typescript, filter, mapped-types

If I have a type like:

```
type T = {
  a: string,
  _a: string,
  b: number,
  _c: boolean,
  /* ... any number of unknown properties ... */
};
```

Is there anyway I can define a new mapped type which has all (and only) properties of `T` which do not begin with the letter `_`?

For instance I want to resolve the above type to `{ a: string, b: number }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can just use [the `Omit<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) where the omitted key type is the *pattern [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types)* `` `_${string}` ``:

```
type FilteredT = Omit<T, `_${string}`>;
/* type FilteredT = {
    a: string;
    b: number;
} */
```

Pattern template literal types were implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598) (but I don't see any handbook or release notes documentation for it).  The type `` `_${string}` `` can be read as "the underscore character followed by any string"; i.e., "any string that starts with an underscore".

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDeAoKUCGAuKBnYATgJYB2A5gDRpQD62ehpl1ARjiQK4C2LEBV6GgGMcLAPZiANhAwkBUAPQAqKADp1mEiCicefKGIBmUDiQDWJMQHcSUMATGQCwIhFxqNShSgC+AbhQUUEgoADEiSWA+CAATOEQAeS4iYAAeGAooAAMaABIkfGJyHyyAPgDlKGDocMjouIRkanR6QqYA9HQ2HW5eAgCfKC8gA)

Comment: Ah wonderful! Btw, in order to do the opposite (*including* the matching keys) I found that `Pick<T, '_${string}'>` was uncooperative as the keys are not guaranteed to exist in `T`. Instead I found this hack works: `Omit<T, keyof Omit<T, '_${string}'>>`. Do you know if there's a better way? (Note I'm using single-quotes instead of backticks in order not to mess up SO's code highlighting)

Comment: @GershomMaes Build your own mapped type: https://tsplay.dev/wje6MW

Comment: @kelsny `{ [K in keyof T & '_${string}']: T[K] }` - that's awesome, thank you!